# URLconnection работа с двумя таблицами

Tags: java, jdbc

Есть две таблицы, одна с primary key, другая с foreign. Соответственно между ними связь по этим ключам.

У меня есть код, работает он таким образом, что пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль, и затем идет проверка, на наличие данного пользователя в базе. Это работа первого urlconnection.

Работа второго urlconnection связана с первым тем, что по этим ключам он вносит в другую таблицу новые данные, допустим, какие-то записи, введенные пользователем.

Все эти махинации написаны в разных классах, у каждого свой сервлет и тд.
Но! Я не знаю каким образом мне вносить данные во вторую таблицу с записями, потому что мне каким-то образом нужно автоматически заполнять foreign key, чтобы прога знала, какому пользователю что принадлежит. 
Покажу на самом коде:

```
public class SignUpToDataBase {
private String name_user;
private String password;
private  int id_user;
public SignUpToDataBase(String name_user, String password){
    this.name_user = name_user;
    this.password = password;}
private void connectToDataBase(){
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement1;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    ResultSet resultSet1;
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, loginDB,  passwordDB);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from  twits where name = '"+ name_user +"' and pass = '" + password + "'");
        if (preparedStatement.execute()){
            System.out.print("Данные зашли" +" "+ name_user + " " + password);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                id_user = resultSet.getInt("id");
                System.out.print(id_user);

            }
```

Здесь, я по имени и паролю узнаю айди пользователя. 
Теперь другой класс.

```
public class WriteTwitToDataBase {


private String twits;
String urlDB = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/notebook";
String passwordDB = "notebook";
String loginDB = "notebook";

public WriteTwitToDataBase(String twits){
    this.twits = twits;
}
public void connectToTwit(){
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, loginDB, passwordDB);

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into user_twits(twits) values(?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1,twits);
        int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0){
            System.out.println("Прошли данные");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Не получилось");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Как мне затащить айди юзера во второй класс. Пробовала создавать отдельный метод, который бы мне возвращал айди юзера, и вызывать его в другом классе, но что-то не прокатило у меня. Помогите, пожалуйста. Может у кого-то есть другие идеи. Если нужно, могу показать код всех классов.

Comment: Вы говорите про сервлеты, т.е. у вас веб приложение? Если это так, то вы можете передавать параметры (в вашем случае юзер айди) многими способами, например через куки(не самый лучший вариант) или как описано тут(по мне вариант получше): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001185/pass-hidden-parameters-using-response-sendredirect
К сожалению что-то больше посоветовать не могу, т.к. не знаю подробностей вашей архитектуры.

Comment: Да, у меня веб приложение. Извините, плохо понимаю английский, но судя по коду, человек используют диспатчер. Я использовала диспатчер, но он был связан с выводом на джсп, но как он может здесь мне помочь, я не особо понимаю. Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Диспатчер там для другого, смотри как он используетServletRequest#getAttribute/setAttribute и HttpSession#getAttribute/setAttribute именно через эти объекты и используя эти методы он передает данные.